# Sum function in Case statement

Tags: oracle, sum, case

I am working on a query where I need to find sum in various condition.Right now my query is:

```
select
sum(case when condition then A_amount end) as S_A_amount,
sum(case when condition then B_amount end) as S_B_amount
```

but in third condition I need to use sum function in When condition also

```
sum(case when sum(C_amount)>3 then 6 else sum(C_amount) end) as S_C_amount
from table A group by item
```

I am unable to implement the third condition. I am getting `not a single group-by` error.

Comment: Please add sample data.

Comment: why? dont need sample. Just only need a subquery to calculate SUM(C_amount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without some sample data it is hard to determine what you are trying to achieve but using `SUM(SUM(value))` within the *same* group is not going to give a different result to just using `SUM(value)` so it appears you could use:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f4d2/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( item, A_Amount, B_Amount, C_Amount, cond ) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 1, 0, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 2, 2, 4 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT item,
       SUM( CASE WHEN cond > 0 THEN A_amount END ) AS S_A_amount,
       SUM( CASE WHEN cond > 0 THEN B_amount END ) AS S_B_amount,
       CASE WHEN SUM(C_amount)>3 THEN 6 ELSE SUM(C_amount) END AS S_C_amount
FROM   A
GROUP BY item
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f4d2/1/0)**:

```
| ITEM | S_A_AMOUNT | S_B_AMOUNT | S_C_AMOUNT |
|------|------------|------------|------------|
|    1 |          4 |          4 |          3 |
|    2 |          8 |          8 |          6 |
```

Comment: where is the SUM? He needs the SUM of the SUMs

Comment: @Thomas Inside the `CASE` expression. The `SUM` of `SUM` is not going to give a different value to just using the `SUM` if the groups are the same in both case - as I commented at the start of the answer - so it is unclear why the OP thinks they need to `SUM` twice.

Comment: I am getting error for third case statement not a group by function.

Comment: @SYMA Updated with some sample data - I cannot replicate your error.

Comment: @MT0: can you introduce one more condition in third case statement. Like Case WHEN SUM(C_amount)>3 and cond>0 then 6 else sum(C_amount) end as S_C_amount

Comment: @SYMA Something like: `CASE WHEN SUM( CASE WHEN cond > 0 THEN C_Amount END ) THEN 6 ELSE SUM( CASE WHEN cond > 0 THEN C_Amount END ) END`?

Comment: why would be same? if he change the value of the sum and after he sums that changed value it wont be equal... ('myitem1', 0,1,3 );('myitem1', 0,1,2 );('myitem2', 0,1,4 )--> your result is 6, my is 12

Comment: @Thomas My sample data has 5 columns but your example is only giving 4 columns (and has no identifiers for those columns) so I cannot determine how you get your results or what the point is you are trying to make.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
select case
          when sum_c_amount > 3 then
           6
          else
           sum_c_amount
       end as s_c_amount
  from (select sum(c_amount) as sum_c_amount
          from table a
         group by item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the existing query into a subquery and place the case expression logic in the outer query layer e.g.

```
select
       d.*
     , case when S_C_amount > 3 then 6 else S_C_amount end
from (
      select
            item
          , sum(case when condition then A_amount end) as S_A_amount
          , sum(case when condition then B_amount end) as S_B_amount
          , sum(case when condition then C_amount end) as S_C_amount
      from t
      group by item
      ) d
```

Comment: Where is the grouping?

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT item,
       sum(case when condition then A_amount end) as S_A_amount,
       sum(case when condition then B_amount end) as S_B_amount,
       sum(case when s_c_amount>3 then 6 else s_c_amount end) as S_C_amount
 FROM (select item,
              A_amount,
              B_amount,
              sum(C_amount) over (partition by item) as s_c_amount
         from table A)
GROUP BY item
```

Comment: The sub-query will contain the `SUM(C_Amount)` in each row (since you are using the analytic function with `OVER (PARTITION BY item)`) and then summing these in the outer query you are effectively doing `SELECT COUNT(1) * SUM(C_Amount) AS S_C_Amount FROM table A GROUP BY item` which is not the output the OP wants. You probably want to use `MAX` instead of `SUM` in the outer query.

Comment: as I said below, why would be same? if he change the value of the sum and after he sums that changed value it wont be equal... ('myitem1', 0,1,3 );('myitem1', 0,1,2 );('myitem2', 0,1,4 )--> your result is 6, my is 12

Comment: why wouldnt matter when the data will change after the first SUM?

Comment: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0f4d2/6) You are counting the sum multiple times.